# slf4j logger doesn't print full package name

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have a project with some classes using org.slf4j.Logger to log some information. The loggers in all other classes are working OK and print full class name, e.g. `INFO com.myapp.gca.servlet.LoginServlet - Entering login`. But for one class, it doesn't print full class name, e.g. `INFO c.m.gca.servlet.HealthCheckServlet - GCA health check OK`, where `com.myapp.` is replaced by `c.m.`.

I couldn't find any difference in this particular class from others. The logger is defined like

```
 private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HealthCheckServlet.class);
```

What may be the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [Conversion Word](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord) table at the official documentation. You have to configure the logger to the length of at least `40` because of the combined package and class name length:

```
%logger{40}
```

However, the `%logger` would be better which always provides the full name.

Answer (score 1):

Use %logger{26} in pattern in logback.xml.

For more details, refer this link.

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html